# strange behavior by sas9.3 indexed dataset

Tags: sas

I am writing the following query in SAS 9.3:

```
CREATE TABLE XYZ AS
select count(distinct x) 
from sasdata.dsn (keep=x);
```

The `sasdata.dsn` is indexed on variables `x` and `y` as a composite index.

What's strange to see is that the query while execution is creating temp files of indexes in sastmp like (as seen)

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21798912 Jun 19 03:18 sastmp-000000008.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21471232 Jun 19 03:18 sastmp-000000009.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21667840 Jun 19 03:19 sastmp-000000010.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21864448 Jun 19 03:20 sastmp-000000011.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21749760 Jun 19 03:21 sastmp-000000012.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21823488 Jun 19 03:22 sastmp-000000013.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21651456 Jun 19 03:23 sastmp-000000014.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21798912 Jun 19 03:25 sastmp-000000015.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21651456 Jun 19 03:27 sastmp-000000016.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21569536 Jun 19 03:29 sastmp-000000017.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21635072 Jun 19 03:31 sastmp-000000018.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21774336 Jun 19 03:33 sastmp-000000019.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21757952 Jun 19 03:36 sastmp-000000020.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21897216 Jun 19 03:38 sastmp-000000021.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21790720 Jun 19 03:41 sastmp-000000022.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21774336 Jun 19 03:44 sastmp-000000023.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21757952 Jun 19 03:48 sastmp-000000024.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21635072 Jun 19 03:51 sastmp-000000025.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21618688 Jun 19 03:55 sastmp-000000026.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21774336 Jun 19 03:58 sastmp-000000027.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21798912 Jun 19 04:02 sastmp-000000028.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21839872 Jun 19 04:06 sastmp-000000029.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21848064 Jun 19 04:11 sastmp-000000030.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21766144 Jun 19 04:15 sastmp-000000031.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21757952 Jun 19 04:20 sastmp-000000032.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21774336 Jun 19 04:25 sastmp-000000033.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21618688 Jun 19 04:30 sastmp-000000034.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21774336 Jun 19 04:35 sastmp-000000035.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21700608 Jun 19 04:40 sastmp-000000036.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21569536 Jun 19 04:46 sastmp-000000037.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21676032 Jun 19 04:51 sastmp-000000038.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 22077440 Jun 19 04:57 sastmp-000000039.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21839872 Jun 19 05:03 sastmp-000000040.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21725184 Jun 19 05:09 sastmp-000000041.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21577728 Jun 19 05:16 sastmp-000000042.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21749760 Jun 19 05:22 sastmp-000000043.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21643264 Jun 19 05:29 sastmp-000000044.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21258240 Jun 19 05:36 sastmp-000000045.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21594112 Jun 19 05:43 sastmp-000000046.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 22175744 Jun 19 05:50 sastmp-000000047.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21708800 Jun 19 05:58 sastmp-000000048.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21880832 Jun 19 06:05 sastmp-000000049.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 21700608 Jun 19 06:13 sastmp-000000050.sas7bndx.lck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 KROUSETLP UNIX_KROGER_DM 12836864 Jun 19 06:17 sastmp-000000051.sas7bndx.lck
```

Is there any reason for this. Also the performance is quite bad so do you have any suggestions on how we can quickly get a distinct count of a variable involved in a composite index.

Comment: Please could you provide a minimal reproducible example? Also, which way around are x and y in the composite index?

Comment: What does it say when you add `feedback` to the sql?

Comment: Thinking about this more I'm not really sure what sort of real performance boost you're going to get from an index in a `select count(distinct)` here.  If your index is a good one [ie, `x` is a discriminating variable, so lots of values] then the distinct query is going to have to look at almost as many values anyway...

Comment: On top of that, you have a composite index on `xy`, which is not the same thing as an index on `x` combined with an index on `y`.  I'm really not sure that SAS/SQL isn't going down a rabbit hole it shouldn't be going down using the index (which I'm not even sure why it's doing that; when I did a brief test it did not do an index scan for this purpose.)

Comment: I just did a test, and the original index seems to be entirely ignored.  I suspect you should consider a different way to do this.  You could try crosstagging this with [tag:sql] and seeing if any of the SQL experts know how to improve this; but as of now I think the issue is that SAS isn't going to use your index (and probably shouldn't), and that's not avoidable as far as I can tell.  There are non-SQL ways to solve this problem, particularly using a data step and a hash table to construct the count, but which makes sense (or if any can save time) depends highly on your data and environment.